# Rename dataframe columns in spark python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a CSV with headings that I'd like to save as Parquet (actually a delta table)

The column headings have spaces in them, which parquet can't handle. How do I change spaces to underscores?

This is what I have so far, cobbled together from other SO posts:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.option("header", True).option("delimiter","\u0001").option("inferSchema",True).csv("/mnt/landing/MyFile.TXT")

names = df.schema.names
for name in names:
    df2 = df.withColumnRenamed(name,regexp_replace(name, ' ', '_'))
```

When I run this, the final line gives me this error:

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

I thought this would be a common requirement given that parquet can't handle spaces but it's quite difficult to find any examples.

Comment: can you try with select: `df.select([col(a).alias(b) for a,b in zip(df.columns,[re.sub(" ","_",i) for i in df.columns])])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `reduce` function to iteratively apply renaming to the dataframe, because in your code `df2` will have only the last column renamed...

The code would look as following (instead of `for` loop):

```py
df2 = reduce(lambda data, name: data.withColumnRenamed(name, name.replace('1', '2')), 
             names, df)
```

Comment: Great. I just had to add `from functools import reduce` to the top of this. So far this is doing what I want - I'll just check out some of the others also

Comment: In this case is the `reduce` function accepting three parameters: the lambda function, names, and df?

Comment: and it seems like `names` is passed to the `name` parameter and `df` is passed to the `data` parameter? Trying to understand what's going on here

Comment: All the examples of reduce that I see take two parameters?

Comment: OK so there are some good examples here showing both ways of doing it (reduce and loop) https://medium.com/@mrpowers/performing-operations-on-multiple-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-36e97896c378

Comment: reduce may accept 2 parameters, in this case, the operation will be executed on the first 2 items of collection - but not on the dataframe. If we use dataframe as 3rd parameter (initial state), then function will be applied to it. In case of 2 parameters function, signature of function is `x: string, y: string`, while in case of 3 parameters,  it will be `x: dataframe, y: string`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception because - function `regexp_replace` returns of type `Column` but function `withColumnRenamed` is excepting of type `String`.

```
def regexp_replace(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern: String,replacement: String): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

```
def withColumnRenamed(existingName: String,newName: String): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`.toDF`** (or) **`.select`** and pass list of columns to create new dataframe.

```
df.show()
#+---+----+----+
#| id|id a|id b|
#+---+----+----+
#|  1|   a|   b|
#|  2|   c|   d|
#+---+----+----+
new_cols=list(map(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "_"), df.columns))

df.toDF(*new_cols).show()

df.select([col(s).alias(s.replace(' ','_')) for s in df.columns]).show()
#+---+----+----+
#| id|id_a|id_b|
#+---+----+----+
#|  1|   a|   b|
#|  2|   c|   d|
#+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I haven't tried your answer but I'm sure I'll come back to it.